# Using object property values in pdo pql statements

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm pretty new to this. I'm hoping someone will be able to advise me why the following code won't work.

I'm trying to post data from an Ajax request to a php script. I'm loading the values in as properties of a "user" object. I'm hoping to then use them to call a database function, but I can't work out why I can't use the object property values in a PDO statement. They're coming up undefined...

Thanks

```
    <?php

class Userclass{
    public $id;
    public $forename;
    public $surname;
    public $greeting = "Mr";
    public function f(){
        call_user_func("dbinsert");
        }
};


try {
    $user = new Userclass;
    $user->id = $_POST["id"];
    $user->forename = $_POST["forename"];
    $user->surname = $_POST["surname"];
    $user->f();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "failed";
    exit;
}


function dbinsert(){
    Require("dbconnect.php");

        try {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO testtable (id, forename, surname)
                VALUES (:id, :forename, :surname)";    
            $insert = $db->prepare($sql);
            $insert->bindValue(':id', $user->id);
            $insert->bindValue(':forename', $user->forename);
            $insert->bindValue(':surname', $user->surname);
            $insert->execute();
            //$insert->execute(array(':id' => $user->id, ':forename' => $user->forename, ':surname' => $user->surname));
            //$insert->execute(array(':id' => "16", ':forename' => "Bill", ':surname' => "Gates"));
            echo $user->forename . " sucessfully added to database";

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "Database insertion failed" . var_dump($e);
        };
}

?>
```

Comment: have you tried putting the try/catch of object inside the function? maybe it's a scope problem

Comment: WHere do you defined the `$user` in dbInsert function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your $user variable is not defined in the dbinsert() scope. You could add your dbinsert() function to the userclass instead. Or set $user as a parameter for dbinsert() instead.

```
   <?php
Require("dbconnect.php");

class Userclass{
    public $id;
    public $forename;
    public $surname;
    public $greeting = "Mr";

    public function dbinsert(){


        try {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO testtable (id, forename, surname)
                VALUES (:id, :forename, :surname)";    
            $insert = $db->prepare($sql);
            $insert->bindValue(':id', $this->id);
            $insert->bindValue(':forename', $this->forename);
            $insert->bindValue(':surname', $this->surname);
            $insert->execute();
            echo $this->forename . " sucessfully added to database";

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "Database insertion failed" . var_dump($e);
        };
    }
};


try {
    $user = new Userclass;
    $user->id = $_POST["id"];
    $user->forename = $_POST["forename"];
    $user->surname = $_POST["surname"];
    $user->dbinsert();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "failed";
    exit;
}

?>
```

Comment: Being very new and self taught, can I trouble you to advise a little further? Just trying to understand things better... If I were to have lots of functions inside the class, and lots of instantiations of that class, I assume it wouldn't create a "heavier" load than having separate functions that are called by one function in the class? Thanks!

Comment: Sure thing, you might not get instant responses though. :P

Comment: I also added "global $user;" just inside the "dbinsert" function. So I've got two ways to do it now. I'll figure out which might be best after I've played with building some of the other parts of my app. Thanks a lot all for your help.

Comment: Regarding execution time; that honestly comes down to the amount of objects your working with and what kind of actions you are going to be doing. Creating a single user object and storing it like in this example is not something to worry about.

Comment: Great, appreciate your time and advice!